# Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 has stopped working after installing the visual studio 2015

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012

Visual studio 2012 is not working after installing the visual studio 2015. I am geting "Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 has stopped working" message the when i am trying to open .aspx page or .cs file in the project. Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

You only need to go into below location

> (%AppData%..\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\ComponentModelCache)

and delete the file `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Default.cache`

It should work.